# Angular full calendar component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I'm using angular full calendar day grid plugin

my json data like this

```
[
{“id”:2,“start_time”:“2019-08-15 16:52:00”}, 
{“id”:3, “start_time”:“2019-09-23 18:55:00”}
]
```

but angular full calendar can recognize data like this

`id: ‘a’, title: ‘my event’, start: '2018-09-01’`

but my json name of date start_time but angular full calendar can recognize start.

how can I fetch my json data to angular full calendar?

Comment: Why not just change your JSON?

Comment: ı cannot change because thats not only my project this is team project

Comment: I see. fullCalendar normally suggests you deal with that using the events-as-a-function pattern, documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . This means you can define your own AJAX call to fetch the data, and then use code to transform it into fullCalendar's format before giving the data to fullCalendar. The example shown in the documentation is about transforming data from XML to JSON, but the same concept applies to transforming from one JSON structure to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() method which iterates through each item of the array in order to map array of object to another array of object.

```
array.map(data=> { return {...data,start: data.start_time} });
```

Here is the sample code.

```
 getEvents() { 
    return this.http.get('http:///api/lessons')
    .map( response => {
       return response.map((data) => {
             return {...data,start: data.start_time};
           });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: getEvents()
  {
    return this.http.get('http:///api/lessons').map( response => response.json().data);
  }

Comment: how should ı use your  suggestion in here

Comment: now ı am getting this error like  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined